# Azure Data Factory - Copy Activity - Source API Request save header response

Tags: azure-data-factory

I use ADF copy activity and the source is API GET request.
This returns response body which I save to storage account but it also provides [HTTP response headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/common-http-request-and-response-headers-used-in-azure-search) which I'd like to save/see.

Is there any way save the response headers to variable or file?

EDIT:

Copy Activity sample response:

```json
{
    "dataRead": 99,
    "dataWritten": 99,
    "filesWritten": 1,
    "sourcePeakConnections": 1,
    "sinkPeakConnections": 1,
    "rowsRead": 1,
    "rowsCopied": 1,
    "copyDuration": 10,
    "throughput": 0.01,
    "errors": [],
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime",
    "usedDataIntegrationUnits": 1,
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "DataMovement",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 1,
                "unit": "DIUHours"
            }
        ],
        "totalBillableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 1,
                "unit": "DIUHours"
            }
        ]
    },
    "usedParallelCopies": 1,
    "executionDetails": [
        {
            "source": {
                "type": "RestService"
            },
            "sink": {
                "type": "AzureBlobFS",
                "region": "Europe"
            },
            "status": "Succeeded",
            "start": "12/12/2023, 2:22:22 PM",
            "duration": 14,
            "usedDataIntegrationUnits": 1,
            "usedParallelCopies": 1,
            "profile": {
                "queue": {
                    "status": "Completed",
                    "duration": 10
                },
                "transfer": {
                    "status": "Completed",
                    "duration": 10,
                    "details": {
                        "readingFromSource": {
                            "type": "RestService",
                            "workingDuration": 10,
                            "timeToFirstByte": 1
                        },
                        "writingToSink": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFS",
                            "workingDuration": 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "detailedDurations": {
                "queuingDuration": 10,
                "timeToFirstByte": 3,
                "transferDuration": 2
            }
        }
    ],
    "dataConsistencyVerification": {
        "VerificationResult": "NotVerified"
    },
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    }
}
```

Web Activity sample response:

```json
{
  "value": [],
  "ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders": {
      "Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
      "x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-tenant-reads": "11999",
      "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
      "x-ms-correlation-request-id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "session-id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "x-ms-correlation-id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "x-ms-client-request-id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "x-ms-request-id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "x-ms-ratelimit-microsoft.consumption-retry-after": "300",
      "x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-microsoft.consumption-requests": "100",
      "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
      "x-ms-routing-request-id": "EUROPE:20231212T121212Z:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "Cache-Control": "private",
      "Date": "Tue, 12 Dec 2023 12:12:12 GMT",
      "Content-Length": "12",
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  },
  "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime",
  "executionDuration": 1,
  "durationInQueue": {
      "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
  },
  "billingReference": {
      "activityType": "ExternalActivity",
      "billableDuration": [
          {
              "meterType": "AzureIR",
              "duration": 1,
              "unit": "Hours"
          }
      ]
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share sample response of API?

Comment: @PratikLad - I added sample response of copy and web activity. I use the copy activity because I save the response body to storage account as mentioned. But web activity does show the header `ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders` which I need. The questions is: Can the Copy activity show also the headers?

Comment: No copy activity dose not show the headers. It will only show the details of copy activity.

Answer (score -1):

**Copy activity does not directly provide a way to read headers from a response and store it for subsequent use. It primarily deals with the data within the response body.** However, you can implement an intermediary solution to address this requirement. by calling API from Web activity and the store the headers into file.

- Output of Web Activity.
  [image]
- Take copy activity to store the headers in storage account
- Use copy activity and have a sample.csv file with one column as the source dataset . Add additional column and provide a new column named  `WebActvityOutput`  with value =  `@string(activity('Web1').output.ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders)`  . In the sink , add the dataset with csv type and give filename with Json extension and set **quote character as no quote character and escape character as no escape characters**. In the mapping tab, click on Import schema and delete the column from sample file and only keep the additionally added column.

[image: jsonweboutput]

**Output:**

[image]